# ASIO Canonical way of running user-provided callbacks in the I/O Service Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, asynchronous

I wrote a TCP client using ASIO that I would like to make a little bit more versatile by adding a user-defined callback for what happens when a packet is received. I am implementing a simple file transfer protocol along with a client protocol that talks to a server, and the only difference should be what happens when data is read.

ELO = Event Loop Owner and refers to the thread running `io_service::run()`

When `socket->async_read_some(...)` is called from the ELO, the data is stored in a `std::shared_ptr<char>` buffer. I would like to pass this buffer to a user-defined callback thread with the definition `std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<char>)>`. However, I'm afreaid that spawning a thread in a `std::shared_ptr<std::thread>` and detaching it is not the best way to go. This is because the stack of detached threads is not unwound.

With some testing, I've found that, if the user provides a callback with a mutex, there is a non-negligible chance that the main thread could exit without the mutex being unlocked (even when using `std::lock_guard`).

Is there any 'safe' way to call a callback in a new thread in an asynchronous program without blocking the event loop or violating thread safety?

Comment: is the data processing really that compute intensive? why not execute the callback in the asio thread? you could also think about using a threadpool where all threads run `io_service::run()`

Comment: The trouble is that the function is user-defined. I have no way of knowing how expensive it is or what the implications of blocking are. Also, I mentioned I'm not using boost, so boost::threadpool is out of the question.

Comment: a threadpool is not tied to boost, you just need to have a couple of threads which all call `io_service::run()`.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I'm running the io service from main() like this:
`std::thread t([&io](void) { io.run(); };` and is later joined after io.stop is called.